# Getting Cucumber tests to run speedily on a Windows box - examples required

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows

I'm trying to set-up a small ruby-on-rails test project to try out some Cucumber testing on a Windows box. I've been able to successfully create a rails project and install Cucumber and run some tests - but the tests run very slowly. I've been pointed by various places at 'Spork' to try and get the tests to run more speedily. I seem to be able to get Spork to run but then when I run the Cucumber tests I get errors complaining about my 'env.rb' file. I've copied the env.rb from the example listed [here](https://github.com/timcharper/spork/blob/master/features/cucumber_rails_integration.feature). The error seems to occur on the

```
require 'spork'
```

line.

Could anyone point me towards a step-by-step tutorial for using Cucumber and Spork on Windows? Failing that is there an example project that I could look at to see how things are typically configured? Finally, is Spork even the right way to go - I've seen some mentions of Autotest and I'm not sure if I'm barking up the wrong tree (I'm a total Rails newb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also learning ROR on windows. I am going through the following tutorial:
http://railstutorial.org

There  is a good explanation on the purpose of autotest and spork in the following part of the tutorial:
http://railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#top

Didn't get to cucumber yet, but looking forward to it.